# Excel VBA Function to Return Address of Value or Text in Array Only Returns #VALUE

Tags: excel, vba

The following code prints the expected cell address in the immediate window but I can't get the cell in the excel spreadsheet for which I type the function formula to return anything but #VALUE!.  For example, in one of my tests, my immediate window is printing the proper result as $F$8 - the proper cell reference of my intended match.

I've also tried varying format options inside the spreadsheet cell where I'm using the function/formula but with the same result.  I'm obviously missing something incredibly simple but I'm embarrassed to say I'm tired of researching what I am hoping will be a very simple answer by this forum.

```
Public Function CellRefInRange(ByVal ItemSearched As Variant, ByVal aRange As Range) As String

Dim cell As Range  
Dim CellRefInRange2 As String

For Each cell in aRange  
      If ItemSearched = cell.Value then CellRefInRange2 = cell.Address  
   Next Cell  
Debug.Print CellRefInRange2  
CellRefInRange = CellRefInRange2  
End Function
```

Comment: How are you calling this? Some sample data or a screenshot perhaps would be nice. As a side note - it really feels like you're reinventing the wheel.

Comment: If `ItemSearched` is a cell error, then the expression `If ItemSearched = cell.Value` is going to throw a type mismatch error, which translates to a `#VALUE!` error on the worksheet in the cell that invoked this function. In order to give you a definite answer, we'd need to know more about how you're invoking it.

Comment: Another potential problem, this will definitely fail if you pass it a multi-cell range as the first argument.